# Laravel 4.x, Auth::check return always false

Tags: database, laravel, authentication

I'm using IIS, so I changed the session driver to 'database' cause other drivers didn't work well.

Then, my auth system has stop working. I made some checks and I've found that `Auth::attempt()` return true and `Auth::check()` always return false.

There is nothing special in my auth, I did it exactly like its described in laravel documentations.

Any suggests?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I did this:

```
Auth::attempt($details)
```

The solution is:

```
Auth::attempt($details, true)
```